# Method not found when calling LIstRequest in grpc from client

Tags: python, django, grpc, grpc-python

I have written a function, to get the list, while connecting the server it show as error method not found:

```
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
    details = "Method not found!"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {created_time:"2023-05-17T02:07:09.472090526+00:00", grpc_status:12, grpc_message:"Method not found!"}"
>
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_question(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body)
    
        survey_response_data = {
                'id' : 'success'
        }
        response = {"errorCode": "", "message": "success", "data": survey_response_data}
        return JsonResponse(data=response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            client_stub = create_new_survey_question_client()
            survey_question = client_stub.List(survey_question_pb2.SurveyQuestionListRequest())
        
            serializer = SurveyQuestionBffSerializer(survey_question, many=True)
            language_data = [msg for msg in serializer.data]
            return JsonResponse(data=language_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)
        except Exception as E:
            data = {"message": f"Exception: {E}"}
            return JsonResponse(data=data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, safe=False)
```

.proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package survey_question;

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service SurveyQuestionController {
    rpc List(SurveyQuestionListRequest) returns (stream SurveyQuestion) {}
    rpc Create(SurveyQuestion) returns (SurveyQuestion) {}
    rpc Retrieve(SurveyQuestionRetrieveRequest) returns (SurveyQuestion) {}
    rpc Update(SurveyQuestion) returns (SurveyQuestion) {}
    rpc Destroy(SurveyQuestion) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}

message SurveyQuestion {
    int32 id = 1;
    string survey = 2;
    int32 question_no = 3;
    int32 question_type = 4;
    int32 order = 5;
    int32 is_required = 6;
}

message SurveyQuestionListRequest {
}

message SurveyQuestionRetrieveRequest {
    int32 id = 1;
}
```

I tried to create a new proto file and checked it still its showing error.

i am using these versions in my env.

```
Django==4.0.7
djangogrpcframework==0.2.1
djangorestframework==3.14.0
exceptiongroup==1.1.1
flake8==6.0.0
futures==3.0.5
google==3.0.0
grpc-django==1.0.0
grpcio==1.54.0
grpcio-reflection==1.54.0
grpcio-testing==1.54.0
grpcio-tools==1.48.1
protobuf==4.22.3
```

survey_question_pb2_grpc.py

```
class SurveyQuestionController(object):
"""Missing associated documentation comment in .proto file."""

@staticmethod
def List(request,
        target,
        options=(),
        channel_credentials=None,
        call_credentials=None,
        insecure=False,
        compression=None,
        wait_for_ready=None,
        timeout=None,
        metadata=None):
    return grpc.experimental.unary_stream(request, target, '/survey_question.SurveyQuestionController/List',
        survey__question__pb2.SurveyQuestionListRequest.SerializeToString,
        survey__question__pb2.SurveyQuestion.FromString,
        options, channel_credentials,
        insecure, call_credentials, compression, wait_for_ready, timeout, metadata)

@staticmethod
def Create(request,
        target,
        options=(),
        channel_credentials=None,
        call_credentials=None,
        insecure=False,
        compression=None,
        wait_for_ready=None,
        timeout=None,
        metadata=None):
    return grpc.experimental.unary_unary(request, target, '/survey_question.SurveyQuestionController/Create',
        survey__question__pb2.SurveyQuestion.SerializeToString,
        survey__question__pb2.SurveyQuestion.FromString,
        options, channel_credentials,
        insecure, call_credentials, compression, wait_for_ready, timeout, metadata)

@staticmethod
def Retrieve(request,
        target,
        options=(),
        channel_credentials=None,
        call_credentials=None,
        insecure=False,
        compression=None,
        wait_for_ready=None,
        timeout=None,
        metadata=None):
    return grpc.experimental.unary_unary(request, target, '/survey_question.SurveyQuestionController/Retrieve',
        survey__question__pb2.SurveyQuestionRetrieveRequest.SerializeToString,
        survey__question__pb2.SurveyQuestion.FromString,
        options, channel_credentials,
        insecure, call_credentials, compression, wait_for_ready, timeout, metadata)

@staticmethod
def Update(request,
        target,
        options=(),
        channel_credentials=None,
        call_credentials=None,
        insecure=False,
        compression=None,
        wait_for_ready=None,
        timeout=None,
        metadata=None):
    return grpc.experimental.unary_unary(request, target, '/survey_question.SurveyQuestionController/Update',
        survey__question__pb2.SurveyQuestion.SerializeToString,
        survey__question__pb2.SurveyQuestion.FromString,
        options, channel_credentials,
        insecure, call_credentials, compression, wait_for_ready, timeout, metadata)

@staticmethod
def Destroy(request,
        target,
        options=(),
        channel_credentials=None,
        call_credentials=None,
        insecure=False,
        compression=None,
        wait_for_ready=None,
        timeout=None,
        metadata=None):
    return grpc.experimental.unary_unary(request, target, '/survey_question.SurveyQuestionController/Destroy',
        survey__question__pb2.SurveyQuestion.SerializeToString,
        google_dot_protobuf_dot_empty__pb2.Empty.FromString,
        options, channel_credentials,
        insecure, call_credentials, compression, wait_for_ready, timeout, metadata)
```

i tried to change the version also, but same error is showing. Can anyone suggest me a solution or right version for protobuf and grpctool.

Comment: Your question does not permit us to repro your issue. Please include the gRPC server implementation for `SurveyQuestionController` service and the `List` method.

Comment: @DazWilkin i have added the SurveyQuestionController. Can you please check now.

Comment: You need to write server implementation of the `SurveyQuestionController` stub code that is generated by `protoc`. Please see [creating a server](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/#server) for an example